# How to convert Gaussian Blur PSD to css3?

Tags: css, photoshop, psd

I want to convert Gaussian Blur PSD to css3?
Someone knows about this, please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is blur property which you can use with css but not gaussian blur. please check below code

`.blur-me {
  filter: blur(20px);
}`

Hope this will help.

---

**Edit:** The `filter` property is supported in [these browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).